# NotMapped attirbute with Required attribute in mvc 3 codefirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have user model with below code in EF CodeFirst mvc3.

```
[NotMapped]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password.")]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string LoginPassword { get; set; }
```

I have below issues with this code block.

1. It is NotMapped, but still giving Modelstate.isvalid false with message Please enter password. How to resolve it?
2. I have javascript on this password field to show indicator (weak, medium, strong). As its Required, when I click submit button without entering any value, its not giving me error as "Please enter password". How to display error message on client side?

Comment: How did you add that javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Are you including these two files in your view?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: @MattSavage..yes i have already included these files in layout page.